# What is $(-1)^{2r-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What is $(-1)^{2r-1}$?

$$(-1)^{2r-1}=\dfrac{(-1)^{2r}}{(-1)}=\dfrac{[(-1)^2]^r}{(-1)}=\dfrac{1^r}{-1}=\dfrac{1}{-1}=-1.$$

Would this be correct? It's quite confusing. Also is it mathematically legal to have a negative sign in the denominator only? Is there a difference being in the denominator vs. the numerator? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: Does it specify that r must be an integer?

Comment: I think it has to be, otherwise it could become an imaginary number correct?

Comment: -1 to an odd power is indeed -1.

Comment: If you think the result itself is also confusing (rather than just the formalities in the proof), you should think of multiplying $-1$ with itself an odd number of times, and the sign flips every time, so it ends up negative. Or you can pair them up two-by-two and a single "-1" will be left over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer focuses on whether or not the simplification is correct, but the question itself asks questions about the representation of rational numbers, which have nothing to do with exponentiation, e.g. "...is it mathematically legal to have a negative sign in the denominator only?"

Remember what a "numerator" and "denominator" are.

In slightly more advanced language, there is no reason to define a "division" operation.  Instead, only multiplication is defined, along with the observation that if $q$ is a rational number, then there exists a multiplicative inverse of $q$, i.e. another rational number $r$<sup>[1]</sup> with the property that

$$qr = 1. $$

There are a couple of notations for this multiplicative inverse:  generally, one writes either

$$ r = q^{-1} \qquad\text{or}\qquad r = \frac{1}{q}. $$

These are two equivalent notations for the same thing.

In this context, there is also no need to define a "subtraction" operation.  Instead, only addition is defined, along with the analogous observation that if $q$ is rational, then there exists an additive inverse $n$<sup>[2]</sup> such that

$$q + n = 0, $$

which is generally denoted by $n = -q$.

The question of where a negative sign "goes" comes down to looking at the three possibilities:  if $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers (integers, probably, though they needn't be), then it is reasonable to ask about the three fractions

$$-\frac{a}{b}, \qquad
\frac{-a}{b}, \qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{a}{-b}. $$

On some level, these three fractions represent three different things:  the first is the additive inverse of $a/b$ (which, itself, is $a$ times the multiplicative inverse of $b$); the second is the additive inverse of $a$, times the multiplicative inverse of $b$; and the third is $a$, times the multiplicative inverse of $-b$ (where $-b$ is the additive inverse of $b$).  In principle, these three things might all be different.

However, in reality, it turns out that all three of these fractions represent the same thing.  That is

$$ -\frac{a}{b} = \frac{-a}{b} = \frac{a}{-b}. $$

In practice, this means that it is "legal" to move negative signs around in a fraction to your heart's content.

---

[1] In my head, I am thinking "$r$ stands for 'reciprocal'".

[2] "$n$ stands for 'negative'".

Answer (score -1):

And yes it is mathematically "legal" to have a negative sign only in the denominator. you can think about it like this : ${2\over-3}$ =${1\over -1} \times 
 {2\over 3}= -1 \times {2\over3}$ and $-1={1\over-1} = {-1\over1}$ so you can have the minus sign in the numerator or the denominator and both of these will mean the same thing!

Comment: It looks like you are saying that $(-x)^k = -(x^k)$ which for sure is incorrect. (e.g. $(-2)^2=4$, not $-4$).

Comment: Or maybe you are using $(-x)^k = -(x^k)$ for odd $k$? Which is true, technically, but it doesn't make much sense to use it when trying to show the much more basic statement in the question. (How would you prove "$(-x)^k = -(x^k)$ for odd $k$" without knowing/understanding the simplest case where $x=1$?)

Comment: @Milten i meant it for odd $k$ but yea you are completely correct there is no reason to use it , thanks for pointing that out!